# Android SingleTask and using StartActivity(Intent) appears to call onCreate() method?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have two activitys defined in my manifest file, one of them is an activity I launch when I click a button inside my application:

```
    <activity android:name=".ui.activity.CustomActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        />
```

In my code, I create an intent and I do

```
startActivity(myIntent)
```

this will correctly launch my activity, but when I call that code again, for some reason it triggers the onCreate and creates a new activity instead of resuming the current one and giving it the new intent contents.

Can someone explain why it is doing this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to use "singleTop" launch mode instead of "singleTask"